# If $f(x)-f(y) \leq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$, is then $f(x) - f(y) = 0$?

Tags: analysis

If $f(x)-f(y) \leq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$, is it true that $f(x)-f(y) =0$? I would guess it is not and $f(x)-f(y)\leq 0$.

If so why is it that if we have $f(x)-f(y) < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$, then $f(x)-f(y) =0$?

Thanks

Comment: are you forgetting the absolute value somewhere?

Comment: You are asking for an interpretation of some words taken out of context. Chances are that you forgot absolute values, and it was $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: varepslion as $\varepsilon$ is prettier : )

Comment: What lion is prettier? :o)

Comment: if f(x) - f(y) < 0 then $\epsilon \ge f(y) - f(x) > 0$

Comment: Does f(x) - f(y) <= e hold for all x, y or just only two specific x, y.  If all then f(x) - f(y) <= e and f(y) - f(x) < = e so |f(x) - f(y)| < e.

Answer (score 2):

There are is no function that satisfies the equation $f(x) - f(y) \leq \epsilon$ for **all** $\epsilon$. That would imply that there is some real number that is a greatest lower bound for all real numbers. In other words, there is a smallest real number. This is contradicted by the fact that the additive inverses of natural numbers are all real numbers, and there is no greatest natural number.

I think what you meant to say was that $f(x) - f(y) \leq \epsilon$ for all values of $\epsilon > 0$. This implies that, no matter how small I choose the value of $\epsilon$, such as $\epsilon = 10^{-100}$, the quantity $f(x) - f(y) \leq 10^{-100}$.

Since there is no real number that is "adjacent to 0", we can keep decreasing the value of $\epsilon$ indefinitely, making the "or equal to" part of the inequality unnecessary. This is assuming you mean "for every value of x and y", this inequality is true.

Without any other qualification, all this would mean is f(x) - f(y) is less than every positive real number. Think about what values that implies for f(x) - f(y). Which real numbers are less than every positive real number ?

From the question you asked afterwards, I can see you're studying the Cauchy formulation of limits. If you considered the question above, you can see that we need the absolute value, representing the "distance" between f(x) and f(y), in our inequality, not merely the difference. We want to say that $|f(x) - f(y)| <\epsilon$ for every value of $\epsilon > 0$. Now, following the same argument above, we see that this means that the distance between f(x) and f(y) is less than every positive real number. Since distance (absolute value) cannot be a negative number by definition, there is now only **one** real number less than every positive real number.

This is the reason we can come to the conclusion you seek. Without the extra requirements, that $\epsilon > 0$ and that we use the absolute value, we can't get that conclusion from what is given at all.